# Importing Lat/Long coordinates as CSV file & only displaying single point in QGIS

Tags: qgis, csv, import

I am using QGIS and trying to import Lat/Long coordinates as delimited text layer. All points show up in my attribute table, however, only one point is displayed on the map? Any ideas?

Comment: Check few points.. Does all lat/lon using same location ?..Try to zoom out in QGIS..Recheck CSV file ..open this file on google earth Pro and confirmed the points..

Comment: @Sunil I don't have google earth pro unfortunately, but i checked everthing else. The CSV file is as simple as 2 columns one with lat in decimal degrees and other with long. thats all. I just can't figure out why i can't see all points. They points are not from the same location. Ive tried zooming in and zooming out etc.

Comment: If possible please upload your csv file to github (or suitable location) OR copy and past few points here..

Comment: @Sunil Lat        Long
48.49549722 123.0003444
48.11882778 123.1360583
48.11745556 123.0172306
48.118725 123.1343611
45.08428333 122.0520361
45.15079167 122.0522028
45.01794444 122.1168806
45.3425         122.6322222

Answer (score 5):

Please check [How to import CSV points into QGIS (Quick tutorial)](http://web.archive.org/web/20171116161828/http://maps.cga.harvard.edu/qgis/wkshop/import_csv.php)

I think some settings (Like projection ,choosing delimiliter etc.) you have to make while importing CSV file in QGIS .Your points are working at my end (Please check the screenshot)

Make sure that please give column name before like lat ,lon (I have not mentioned in my case)

[image: Screen-shot 1 :]

[image: Screen-shot 2]

Let us know if you have any questions..thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should add a header line "N E" first. Otherwise the first row does not get imported.

These headers will form the column (field) names of the attribute table. Numbers only might prevent the data from being accepted.

And make sure you don't have messed up lat and lon. lat is only valid +/- 90°, lon values +/- 180°

Answer (score 0):

Check your scale, have you zoomed-in to the point to see if they are atop one another? Also, as stated above, it could be that the lat/lon is imported as the same. It may be that the .csv file rounded the lat/lon data and they appear as the same values in QGIS. I wrote a blog post on importing .csv lat/lon values, check it out for a tutorial on doing this correctly (with open-source data).

https://engineersportal.com/blog/2017/10/30/geospatial-analysis-using-qgis-and-open-source-data

Answer (score 0):

I have had issues importing Lat and Long data from CSV files in the past and I have found unchecking "Discard Empty Field" often helps.

[image]