# QGIS: Creating Circles Around Points Imported from a Excel File (Lat, Long)

Tags: qgis, geoprocessing, qgis-plugins, qgis-2

I am new to the QGIS platform and have been experimenting with the tool. I currently have a Basemap layer and a Shapefile layer on top of it. Now,

1. I want to import a .csv file containing (lat, long) coordinates for a set of points (say 20) as a layer.
2. I want to create a layer( or superimpose in the above layer), circles of a specified radius around each of these points.

How do I do these?

Comment: Be aware that if you want proper metric circles, you will have to convert your layer to a metric system.

Comment: You've answer from myself and Joseph that approach your problem in different ways. Were you after a style solution or a dedicated layer showing a boundary around a point (buffer)?

Comment: If it is possible to use PostGIS then proper metric circles can be created by using geography instead of geometry. Or to cast a geometry to geography for computing the metric buffer and then back to geometry. The SQL would look like `select cast (ST_Buffer(cast(ST_GeomFromText('POINT (-3 70)',4326) as geography),10000) as geometry)` See also http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/157848/converting-from-kilometers-to-degrees-distances/157872

Comment: @MikeRSpencer I am really really sorry that my comments are coming in so late... Yes I was looking for a dedicated layer and not a style.

Comment: @bugmenot123 yes i want proper metric circles, but I guess I would be able to achieve that with a proper CRS (UTM regional)?

Comment: @user30184 Avoiding PostGIS and the helps due to current lack of knowledge.

Comment: Lack of knowledge is a problem that you can solve.  Learn to use Spatialite if you want to avoid the trouble of administrating PostGIS. Here is a Spatialite query that turns lon-lat coordinates into suitable UTM zone, buffers the point with 50 km radius, and projects the result back to lon-lat `SELECT ST_Transform(ST_Buffer(ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText('POINT (-110 55)',4326),32612),50000),4326)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you want to buffer your point layer?

- Load your data as Joseph describes
- Go to the menu Vector/Geoprocessing Tools/Buffer(s)
- In the dialogue box choose your input layer (possibly only accepts shp - so you might need to save your csv as shp first)
- then set your buffer distance and specify an output file.

Other parts of the dialogue box are optional. You can read more in the QGIS docs: http://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/gentle_gis_introduction/vector_spatial_analysis_buffers.html

Comment: Yes, I think you're right that the OP wants a buffer instead of a style. +1 :)

Comment: Their intention was not helped by the style tag! Will wait to see if they clarify.

Comment: The style tag was my doing...0_0. I will remove it and as you say, wait for the OP to clarify.

Comment: @MikeRSpencer your buffer will most probably be in degrees, so I suggest to reproject to UTM or another projected CRS when saving to shapefile.

Comment: No doubt, but the OP didn't specify what units of radius they were after.

Comment: Thanks to both of you, and yes, I was looking for a buffer. Also, my radius units are in meters. So, I am hoping a UTM CRS will help me there. Just changing my CRS to UTM <regional code> will make my buffer units in metres, right?

Comment: Maybe, you might need to reproject the file, you can do this by right clicking in the layer list and choosing save as.

Answer (score 3):

You can [import your csv file with lat/lon data](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/52388/importing-lat-long-coordinates-as-csv-file-only-displaying-single-point-in-qgi?rq=1) by going to *Layer > Add Delimited Text Layer* and check the 'Points coordinates' as the geometry definition:

[image: Add delimited text layer]

Once imported, you can change the style by double-clicking the layer to access its properties, go to the **Style** tab, select the *Simple marker* option and change its options such as colour, size etc. You can change the size to specified millimeters or set it accordingly to the map units:

[image: Style options]

Hope this helps!