# QGIS add CSV - only shows 2 points on map

Tags: qgis, csv, qgis-2.12

When I add a delimited text file to QGIS, only two points show up (but there are 122 points in the attribute table). I've seen answers to this question [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/52388/importing-lat-long-coordinates-as-csv-file-only-displaying-single-point-in-qgi) and [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/186637/csv-points-not-showing-up-when-importing-them-in-qgis), but neither solved my issue.

Here's my process:

1. Start with Excel spreadsheet (I'm working on a Mac) and save as a Windows CSV.
2. In QGIS, add delimited text file. Select "CSV" as file format and point coordinates (lat and long columns in spreadsheet). Choose WGS1984 as CRS.
3. See screenshot for result- only two points show up, even though the attribute table shows the full dataset.

[image: QGIS map view]

[image: QGIS attribute table view]

I've tried exporting the file as a shapefile, saving the CSV in different formats before importing it, and watching tutorials to make sure I'm doing everything correctly, to no avail. I have had this issue before, and could never solve it. Any feedback would be great. I'm using QGIS v. 2.12.

Comment: This is a common problem with Excel on Mac, see http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/137260/qgis-wont-read-table-columns-in-csv-import-on-mac-os

Comment: @AndreJ my data imports in columns, not as a string (different from the Q you linked to). I've tried windows CSV, same issue.

Comment: The negative scale seems strange and coordinates don't match WGS84. Can you load a Natural Earth shapefile first, and see which features are imported by labelling with the id field? Does your locale use decimal commas?

Comment: Can you confirm whether you have only two points or whether all the points are stacked on top of each other.  Also please confirm that when you say you set the CRS to WGS84, you chose EPSG:4326 and not EPSG:3857

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try sorting your latitude column in descending order. I suspect you have a typo in one of the values that makes it much larger than the others. When I look at the image of your canvas, the lower dot appears to be multiple stacked dots.

After sorting, the offending point(s) should be at the top row(s). Once you remove or fix the offending point, right-click on the nigeriapop layer and choose "Zoom to layer"